# EF Core creates an expensive new database in Azure SQL if it doesn't already exist

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, ef-core-6.0

I use Azure SQL server and EF Core 6.

I execute a migration to a connection string with a db name that doesn't exist, but a server that does. Azure (or EF Core?) then automatically creates the DB in the server. The problem is that it uses a default pricing plan that is far to expensive. This automatic DB creation is not something I intend, I try to prevent it, but because of a bug it tried to migrate a non-existing DB. Can I change this default pricing plan in Azure or deactivate this behavior in EF Core?

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question. Why wouldn't you just migrate to a database that does exist? Or if you don't want a database at all, don't migrate? Also - can you change a pricing plan in Azure - yes of course you can.

Comment: Like I said, it's a bug on my part, the DB doesn't exist, so the migration shouldn't happen. But if a similar bug happens in the future I'd like to avoid having a new useless expensive DB. And I didn't ask about changing the plan, I asked how I could change the default pricing plan. If I can set it to be "basic" it will be far less expensive.

Comment: Limit the rights of the account running the migration

Comment: I think it is incorrect to say "the DB doesn't exist, so the migration shouldn't happen". Migrations are supposed to create DBs if they don't exists - that's normal behavior for migrations. I understand your question - so I just want to clarify the situation with what you can expect EF to do when you run migrations.

Comment: I'm referring to my own code, a migration shouldn't happen if the DB doesn't exist. But that's not really important. I just want to change the default pricing plan or deactivate this auto creation in EF if that exists.

Comment: check if this link helps you to solve the issue. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/100652/entity-framework-automatically-creates-database-wh.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/100652/entity-framework-automatically-creates-database-wh.html)